# How to access class members from input change listener in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to Angular and i know that my question is about scopes  but i could not find the same case in questions asked before, so  i am trying to better explain my question with code and comments below:

```
        @Component({
          selector: 'item-selector',
          templateUrl: './item.component.html'
        })
        export class ItemComponent implements OnInit {

          items: ITem[];  // ITem is my model, it has a numeric property called : price
          totalPrices = 0; // this variables should always hold the total of prices in the items array (sum of item.price)
          
          
          ngOnInit()  {
            items = data from server....
          }

           

          onPricesChange(event): void { // fired when change happens in price 
            // The question is here : how to access the list of Items here ? (to update the totalPrices field)
            // this.items returns undefined
           }
           
           
          deleteFromItems(item: ITem) {
             // On the other hand, the list of Items (this.items) is well referenced HERE from the click listener !!!
          }
        }

        <tr *ngFor="let item of items">
            <td><input type="number"  [(ngModel)]="item" (input)="onPriceChange($event)">
            </td>
            <td class="text-right">
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <button type="submit" (click)="deleteFromItems(item)"
                            class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
                        <fa-icon [icon]="'times'"></fa-icon>
                        <span class="d-none d-md-inline" >Delete</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in data from your *ngFor. In your example below I added item, items to your onPriceChange() call.

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of items">
            <td><input type="number"  [(ngModel)]="item" (input)="onPriceChange($event, item, items)">
            </td>
            <td class="text-right">
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <button type="submit" (click)="deleteFromItems(item)"
                            class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
                        <fa-icon [icon]="'times'"></fa-icon>
                        <span class="d-none d-md-inline" >Delete</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

```
onPricesChange(event, item, items): void { // fired when change happens in price 
            // The question is here : how to access the list of Items here ? (to update the totalPrices field)
            // this.items returns undefined
           }
```

Comment: But this.items is not accessible from inside onPricesChange.

Comment: You wouldn't use this.items in my example. Items is passed into the function from the template. Simple use items.forEach in the onPriceChange

Comment: Also this.items shouldn't be undefined if you have a list showing based off of items array. You may have a bigger issue that we can't see here. If you can repro using a stackblitz it would help.

Comment: I used your example and got items undefined in items.forEach

Comment: You'll need to reproduce this on a stackblitz.

Answer (score 0):

you can try do the following  :

1. in the view try to send the item object instead of $event like :

   ```
   <td><input type="number"  [(ngModel)]="item" (input)="onPriceChange(item)"></td>
   ```
2. in the component file on the onPricesChange() method update it like the following:

onPricesChange(item : ITem): void {
this.items.ForEeach(data=> {

```
            if (data.id == item.id) {
                if(data.price != item.price) {
                    this.totalPrices -=data.price;
                    this.totalPrices += item.price;
                } 
            }
            });
       }
```

Comment: Same thing !! this.items is always undefined.

Comment: try to initialize it when you declare it like that:   `items: ITem[]  = []`

Comment: I initialize it and it is always undefined, i think it is a problem of scope

Comment: can you please send me the full code snippet for the component .ts file?